# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable for csv_read

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read the data from `.csv` file by using the code line below.

```
production = pd.read_csv("time_series_60min_singleindex.csv",
                        usecols= (lambda s: s.startswith('utc') | 
                        s.startswith('DE')),
                        parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
```

But I am having error

> "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCqQ6.jpg) of traceback is also added.

Comment: Is this a Pandas question? If so, you should give it the pandas tag. It looks like you have given a function name instead of calling the function, but there isn't enough context to answer your question properly. Please add the full error Traceback, and the lines of code that it mentions, preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added the traceback as an image

Comment: Hi, I'm almost not able to reproduce your error. The only thing I can say is that you don't need the braces around the lambda function, independant of its length.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error with pd.read_excel. Check your version of pandas. For example, 0.16.2 does not enable passing of functions to parameter usecols (or parse_cols). In python:

```
import pandas
pandas.version.version
```